# Regex for modifying access modifiers

Tags: regex

I would like to modify all the private methods to public. (I want only methods not variables defined as private)

Is there any way with notepad++ to do it with a regex for example ?

I am trying something like that :

- Find What   : (private) +[\w\<>[]]+\s+(\w+) *([^)]*) *({?|[^;])
- Replace     :  public
- Search Mode :  Regular Expression

But it does not work

Could you help me please ?

Comment: show a few examples

Comment: Do you have **perl** or **ack** on your windows?

Answer (score 1):

This Should Work.

RegExp:

```
(private)(.+\n*\s*\{)
```

Replace with

```
public$2
```

Input:

```
private static void main(String[] args) 
{
}

private static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

Output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```